# sony flashtool installation Error

Tags: flash, sony

I was facing error in installing sony flashtool.
But I was able to solve it on my own.

[here is the log.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rACfc.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What error...? 
   It was asking u, ID......! 
   step -1,install Emma software (don't finish it) 
  Step -2 before finishing the Emma software 
It installing folder open (program file, Sony, Emma 
Step -3 open the extract file on Emma software to copy (custamization. ini.) then

```
    Paste to the Emma installing folder
```

Final step.... After finish button click

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Windows 10? As windows 10 is not supported. That error similar to the one I have.

Comment: windows 10 is supported.

Comment: It wasn't at the time of question